# Problems with appending innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I have the following textarea html to help solve the problem of the placeholder text value not dissapearing on focus using the placeholder value when using IE10

```
<textarea id="answerText" name="answerText" placeholder="Your answer here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = \'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Your answer here...\'">@answer.Text</textarea>
```

This is rendering as expected for the first answer but when trying to append a textarea for a second answer using javascript the onfocus and onblur events dont seem to be working as when I click on the textarea the placeholder value remains. here is my code:

```
 $('#answerList').append('<li><div class="row"><div class="eight columns"><textarea id="answerText" name="answerText" placeholder="Your answer here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = \'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Your answer here...\'"></textarea></div><div class="four columns"><input type="checkbox" name="correctCheckbox" id="correctAnswerCheckbox' + answerPosition + '" value="' + answerPosition + '"/><label for="correctAnswerCheckbox' + answerPosition + '">Correct Answer</label></div></div></li>');
```

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle to demonstrate this?

Comment: Are you creating a new textarea with exactly the same id? IDs should be unique for each element. I'd suggest you use a class, and bind your events to the css class. Also when are you appending the new textarea? If it's via ajax, then you need to look at how you are binding the event. You should use a function such as jquery's "on" function and have a parent element that is always on the page. But a fiddle or some more code would help

Comment: Sounds like an ID issue... check that the newly generated placeHolder has a different ID than the Previous one(s)

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
var $newField = $('<li><div class="row"><div class="eight columns"><textarea class="answerText" name="answerText" placeholder="Your answer here..."></textarea></div></div></li>').appendTo('#answerList');
$newField = $newField.find('.answerText');
$newField.on('focus', function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', '');
});
$newField.on('blur', function() {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', 'Your answer here...');
});
```

Im assuming the inline even handlers dont get registered after the initial page rendering.

I generally find it more effective to manage event handling in my js files, as opposed to inlining them into the dom. So if there is no special reason for using inline event handlers, id propose not to.

edit:

Changed classes to IDs, as pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to change much in your codes, you could try to add a counter that will some how give them different Ids:

```
var ctr=0;

$('#answerList').append('<li><div class="row"><div class="eight columns"><textarea id="answerText'+crt+'" name="answerText" placeholder="Your answer here..." onfocus="this.placeholder = \'\'" onblur="this.placeholder = \'Your answer here...\'"></textarea></div><div class="four columns"><input type="checkbox" name="correctCheckbox" id="correctAnswerCheckbox' + answerPosition + '" value="' + answerPosition + '"/><label for="correctAnswerCheckbox' + answerPosition + '">Correct Answer</label></div></div></li>');

ctr++; /// ctr +1;
```

then add ctr +1 in then loop.

This assumes a reiteration is in palce and will solve the ID issue.

Should you have like 500 `textareas`, If you wish to call the 300th, you could do:
`$('textarea[id*="300"]')`

or if you wish to call all of them in the mixture of others:

```
$('textarea[id*="answerText"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the expected behavior for a [placeholder](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) is to not disappear until something is typed into the box.

However, if you still want to make it show/hide on focus/blur, I recommend to assign some class to the textarea elements, and bind the focus and blur events from the javascript code.

I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajghL/) to illustrate my point.

```
<textarea id="answerText" name="answerText" placeholder="Your answer here..." class="answer">@answer.Text</textarea>


$('#add').on('click', function(){
    $('<textarea class="answer" placeholder="text here" ></textarea>').appendTo('#answers');
});
//#answers is the container for the answers
$('#answers').on('focus', '.answer', function(){
    this.placeholder = '';
});

$('#answers').on('blur', '.answer', function(){
    this.placeholder = 'text here';
});
```

In this way the code will be more maintanable and decoupled, and as a side effect you will avoid the issue you are having.